is it safe to delete the jre-1.8 folder from program files
I am wondering if it is safe to delete the jre-1.8 folder from program files, as it takes up 20 gigs on my 120-gig hard drive. I am not planning to replace java, and will redownload it if needed, but 20 gigs, really?
The problem I have is storage. I see no reason for java to take up 1/6 of my hard drive space. I have already tried finding anything else to remove, but can't,. Java is the largest thing on my drive.

It is safe to delete but will likely cause some locally installed programs to stop working, naturally anything that uses Java.
If you do decide to delete it, you'll get a cleaner removal if you use the Java Uninstall Tool:
https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/msi-jre/install-guide/uninstalling-jre-java-removal-and-uninstall-tools.htm#JSMSI115

It’s safe, but probably not necessary.
Typically, a Java Runtime Environment (JRE) installation should only take up a few hundred megabytes, not 20 gigabytes!
I would definitely take a look at the jre-1.8 folder and see if any subfolders like lib or temp contain a large amount of data.
Most likely clearing any caches and log files in the folder will reduce the space it takes up drastically.

Not sure why this was downvoted -- on this PC, Java (JRE SE only) is 221 MB. 20 GB is 200 x larger. That said, use the Java uninstaller, don't manually delete the folder.

@DrMoishePippik Yes, thanks. I did think it was pretty unusual for a JRE install to be that big.

The question and both answers were downvoted.
